# Why is the inverting gain of this phase shift oscillator 8?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, impedance, virtual-ground

In this oscillator configuration, which I got from the textbook "Operational Amplifiers & Linear Integrated Circuits" by James Fiore (page 354, 3rd edition), since the gain of the ladder network is -1/8, the inverting gain is designed using the formula

Rf/Ri= -8,

so that the loop gain be 1, where Rf=8M and Ri=1M

However, the 100k resistor seems to be in parallel with the 1M resistor. The ladder network seems to be relatively unaffected by this since 1M is a pretty large value and maybe neglected. However, it seems to me that the inverting gain would be something like

Rf/Ri +Rf/100k,

with the latter term dominating.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100k is not in parallel with the 1M resistor.

Whatever voltage at V3 is, the op-amp senses that through 1M resistor only.

Therefore op-amp output only needs to balance the current of 1M resistor with the 8M resistor, so the amplifier has gain of -8.

The 100k will affect the voltage V3 because it is a load for the RC network, but that does not affect how the op-amp senses the voltage V3.

Comment: `The 100k is not in parallel with the 1M resistor.` If we assume ideal opamp then shouldn't they're in parallel?

Comment: @internet Opamp being ideal or not does not affect it. The point is, to the capacitor, it has two loads, 100k and 1M. But the resistors are not in parallel. They do not share two nodes. And only the current through 1M resistor affects the op-amp. To the op-amp, there could be 100k or 1k or whatever. Op-amp still reacts only to current through 1Mohm.

Comment: @internet Two nodes being forced to the same voltage does not make them the same node.

Answer (score 2):

- The damping factor of the shown CR-network (node "V3") at the frequency with a phase shift of 180deg (fo=916 Hz) is k=0.10725.
- Therefore, you need a gain of at least G=-9.32 in order to allow oscillation at 916 Hz. However, due to the large resistor values (Mega-ohm-range) the simple gain expression (-R2/R1) will be, most probably, not accurate enough (the opamps input resistance comes into the game).
- Recommendation: Completely drop the 1M resistor and connect the 100k resistor directly to the opamp input. In this case, the oscillation frequency reduces to app. fo=888.3Hz and the required gain is app. G=-9.26.
  (feedback resistor: R2=930k).

Comment: I get the same results for fo and k. (If I don't take into account the loading of the 1 M to the virtual ground.) I'll +1. What bothers me is that I can't see how this thing gets built. Even tiny trace capacitance around that 8 M resistor would further increase the gain requirements. But noise should also be a problem, too. I guess I'm just not happy with it right now.

Comment: Yes - the resistors are too large. Therefore my recommendation at the end of my contribution. It is not necessary to have the two resistors (100k and 1M) in parallel. Only one resistor is needed.

Comment: Agreed on that point.